# Firefox Emulate Print Styles

Tags: css, firefox

Since the [Developer Toolbar is removed](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/05/21/firefox-62-developer-toolbar-removal/), I wonder if there is an alternative to emulate the print styles.

Does anybody know, if there is an equivalent to `media emulate print`?

Comment: Look at the print preview?

Comment: With `media emulate print` it was possible to use the Inspector. With the print preview it isn't.

Comment: You're right, sorry. There is "Inspect element" in the print preview, but it doesn't actually show any styles! I don't know then, we'll have to wait for a new add-on to come along. Until then, maybe install an older version of FF in a virtual machine and test with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in [this post](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-to-media-emulate-print-without-developer-toolbar-gcli/30975/25) it's now possible. Once you open the Inspector and have opened the CSS rules tab, you can click a small page icon to toggle the print view.

[image: animated GIF, which shows what happens when switching the print preview]
(GIF [from the post](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-to-media-emulate-print-without-developer-toolbar-gcli/30975/25))